# ускорение Kivy с помощью numba

Tags: python, kivy, numba

Можно ли использовать numba для ускорения kivy и как ? Есть другие варианты ускорения kivy?(приложения для андроида)

Comment: для ускорения чего? всего приложения? или каких-то конкретных операций? Приложение на пк или телефон ? Если на мобилку то точно нет.